# exception when using ipy64 with pypyodbc

Tags: ms-access, driver, ironpython, pypyodbc

I'm trying to create a database with MSAccess using pypyodbc on Ironpython. I have this working perfectly fine on my old machine, but I must migrate to a new machine. However on the new machine I get an exception trying to run the same script.

Using python I can create a database without errors.

> ipy
>
> import pypyodbc
>
> pypyodbc.win_create_mdb('C:\database.mdb')
>
> pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\database.mdb;')

However, if I try the same using ipy64 I get an Exception

> "Access Driver is not found"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\IronPython27\pypyodbc.py", line 2564, in win_create_mdb
>
> Exception: Access Driver is not found.

I installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 as I have 64-bit office products installed.

Thanks,

John.

Comment: If I run >ipy pypyodbc.drivers() I get "File pypyodbc.drivers() does not exist" However, pypyodbc-1.2.1 is installed on both machines.

Comment: I've since discovered that I can create a database on the new machine with pypyodbc. I get the error if I try and share this database between machines (e.g copy the db I have to the new machine) or execute any writes to the database on the new machines once I've recreated it. Based on this, I'm thinking its something to do with my access drivers.